# print elements of list as string in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list of strings that contain a letter and number pair, for example
    a=["B8", "C1", "B4", "A3"]

I'd like to be able to use this list and combine it (without brackets, commas, or quotation marks) with a base string "You have" in a print statement to tell the user
    You have B8 C1 B4 A3

It doesn't seem possible to do this using the .join() and .append() methods.

Comment: Nothing is as it seems ;-)

Comment: Please show how you have tried, and in what way(s) they failed.

Answer (score 1):

[str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and [str.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) will do exactly what you want:

```
a = ["B8", "C1", "B4", "A3"]
print("You have {}".format(" ".join(a)))

In [6]: a=["B8", "C1", "B4", "A3"]
In [7]: print("You have {}".format(" ".join(a)))
You have B8 C1 B4 A3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=["B8", "C1", "B4", "A3"]
print "You Have " + " ".join(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=["B8", "C1", "B4", "A3"]
for item in a:
    print 'You have',item
```

Hope this was helpful.